# NodeJS Server Side MP3 'Playback'?

Tags: node.js, html, audio, icecast

This is my current approach to *fake* a Radio-Like stream with node.

**Node ReadStream**

This ReadStream just reads an mp3 and streams it to a html5 based audio player.

––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

**Counter**

This counter represents the current playback position of the RadioStream.
It keeps incrementing each second to simulate playback. Once a client connects to the server, the stream will start at the counters position. The only thing which I do not get around is the correct increment size of the counter.

––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

Or is there a way to offset a mp3 stream by seconds ?

**Metadata**

Once I have the correct position, it will be super easy to build a playlist with Metadata, such as Song Name, Composer etc and push them to the client via socketio.

––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

If you have an idea how to solve this better please let me know.

I also tried using icecast with the following source clients :

- vlc: cuesheet support is buggy, it is not forwarding metadata
- Liquidsoap : cuesheet support is buggy, it is not forwarding
  metadata

I tried executing ezstream with node and start the counter which increments in seconds, but the counter gets very fast out of sync.

Looks like my approch is anything else than ideal, so how to solve this in a smarter way *please*?

Comment: I'm also looking for something like this. A server side audio playback with nodejs

Comment: I ended up using icecast for playback and parsing the stream with node to extract metadata